# Typescript object as function argument

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, arguments

```
transforms: {
   webpackConfiguration?: ExecutionTransformer<webpack.Configuration>,
} = {}
```

While reading some code from an Angular project I found this piece above which gets passed as an function argument. In my understanding the argument `transforms` is an object with one key value pair, the `?` means that `webpackConfiguration` is optional which confuses me because it is the only key-value-pair entry. What does the `= {}` mean at the end of the code above?

Comment: It is the default value of `transforms` in case you don't provide?

Comment: makes sense! Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

It is the default value of `transforms` argument in case you don't provide it. Whatever follows the `=` is considered to be the default value so, in this case, `transforms` will be set to a new empty object `{}` if you don't pass a value to the function. Take the following function `fun` as example:

```
function fun(arg1: { bool?: true } = {}, arg2: boolean = false) {

}
```

If you don't provide `arg1`, it will be set to `{}` and if you don't provide `arg2`, it will be set to `false` in the function `fun`.